# Change ip address link to be http instead of https

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I recently abruptly changed domains because my old domain got hacked. I bought a new domain, but it doesn't show in google search results yet. I submitted a crawl request via google search console but I'm told it could take a week. In the meantime, when people search my website up, the ip address of my server pops up in the search results. I already edited my nginx config to redirect the ip to my new domain.

The problem is that when I click the ip address link, it tries to use https, and becuase I don't have SSL certificate for the ip, chrome shows the "invalid certificate, connection not secure, return to safety" screen. This is causing my nginx's redirect to my new domain to never go through. How do I make it so that the ip address uses http instead of https? I think if I make that happen, then my users will be successfully redirected to the new domain that has SSL.

Comment: Please post your full `nginx` configuration.

Comment: i would suggest that you take the time to tell what you mean with my domains goot hacked? i mean you can provide the proof of ownership or not?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the best approach here would be to just enable SSL on your webserver. You can get a free SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt and install that on your server or get a free subscription to a CDN like Cloudflare that will also provide you with an SSL certificate when routing traffic through their network. Not using SSL will cause your site to rank poorly in google search results and many browsers nowaydays connect to https by default.
So in the long run not using SSL will cause you lots of problems and it's probably better to solve that sooner rather than later.

Comment: can I get SSL for a ip address link? I don't think thats possible with lets encrypt

Comment: Ah okay, yes, I see the problem. You could also try to disable https on your nginx that does the redirect. I'm not sure if clicking on a Google link would then timeout or reach the http port of the server. Would be worth a try. Else you'll probably have to wait for Google to refresh their index..